# PowerBI visual filter "is not 0" returns blank graph

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In PowerBI Desktop, I have a graph visual where I want to show the bottom 25 values. Some of the values in my data set are 0, and I want to filter these out from the bottom 25. I add a filter for the numeric value set to "is not 0", and then set my name field to "Top N", show items: bottom 25, by value [numeric value] field. When I do this, my graph turns blank. Why does this happen? I assumed that the filters reduced the data set based on their order.

If I set the bottom N to 144, I get results populating the graph and it shows ones where the value is >= 1. The data set is dynamic so I can't hardcode this value. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filters are applied independently rather than sequentially after applying previous filters, so you can't have one filter dependent on the result of another one.

For a mixed filter like this, you'd probably need to write part of the filtering yourself as a measure. For example, assuming you're grouping on some category, you can write a nonzero version of whatever you're interested in like this

```
NonZeroMeasure =
CALCULATE ( [Measure], FILTER ( VALUES ( Table1[Category] ), [Measure] <> 0 ) )
```

Then you can use the Top N filter with this modified measure.

[image: Filter Panel]